# ListViewItem in WPF ListView

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to get the ListViewItem object from the currently selected row of a data bound ListView, like so:

```
ListViewItem selectedItem = new ListViewItem();
selectedItem = (ListViewItem)listView1.Items[index];
```

what this does however, is returns the object type the ListView is bound to, in this instance, its a company class object for a database. What I would like it to return is the actual ListViewItem object itself (so that I can access its properties).

is there anyway to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use,

```
ListViewItem selectedListView = 
    (ListViewItem)listView1.ItemContainerGenerator.GetContainerForItem(
        listView1.Items[index]);
```

Comment: You sir, are a god amongst men, THANK YOU!! :)