# Grab ListViewItem objects out of ListView by index instead the data objects - Windows 10 Universal

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal

Actually we can make it short. I want to do the exact same thing as this guy wanted to do in his post:
[ListViewItem in WPF ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895395/listviewitem-in-wpf-listview)

He has done it in WPF but I´m in Windows 10 Universal App development. I tried the same and realized that the method  `listView.ItemContainerGenerator.GetContainerForItem();`

isn´t working there because `.GetContainerForItem();` doesn´t exist.

Does anyone know how to do this in Windows 10 Universal App development?

Comment: You can just use `listview.GetContainerForItem(item);`

Comment: ListView hasn´t that method. It has 5 methods starting with get. These are:

Comment: GetAnimationBaseValue(), GetBindingExpression(), GetHashCode(), GetValue(), GetType()

Comment: You have to use ListView instance(name which you give to the control) not ListView class itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ItemsControl` class contain 2 methods which can be used for your requirement.

```
public DependencyObject ContainerFromIndex(System.Int32 index);
public DependencyObject ContainerFromItem(System.Object item);
```

The `ListView` derives from the `ItemsControl` class, hence will support these methods.

Example:

```
ListViewItem item = listView.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListViewItem
```

or

```
ListViewItem item = listView.ContainerFromItem(item0) as ListViewItem
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is awesome.